# How does the Android system tell an application that this app has gone to the background (invisible)?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, system, xposed-framework

I am trying to make an **Xposed module** to hook the function of the Android System where it tells the application A, that it has gone to the background.
In other words, here is an example:
We are using application A, and then we press the home button, or enter another app. The system will send a message to our application A to let it know that the focus has been changed, and now it is in the background (the user can no longer see it). The system does this so the application can run the *onPause()* method and so on.

I posted on XDA, in the Xposed section, and even though I was able to narrow it down, I wasn't able to solve it. [LINK](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/hook-onpause-app-to-redirect-to-onresume-t3137026)

I also have been searching a lot in the Android repositories of github and grepcode, but haven't been able to find which method does it. I'm a little lost.
These are the links I got:

1. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/Instrumentation.java#1234
2. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/Activity.java#5346
3. https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/19a2266fed147ae051ba2df74f755cd7427c6eaa/docs/html/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.jd

Thanks, any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, and it makes lot of sense. But it takes lot's stuff to do, for example.

1). You need to make your app as boot start-up means whenever user restart mobile or device your app should automatically start's.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".OnGPSReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```

2). Obviously you have to make app with no launcher mode as it's first activity and then call second activity as a service not as an activity.

so basically you have to create something like this.

```
public class AppService extends WakefulIntentService{
   // your stuff goes here
```

}

and while calling service from your mainActivity define it like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppService.class);
```

startService(intent);
hideApp(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

hideApp // use it outside the mainActivity.

```
private void hideApp(String appPackage) {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(appPackage, appPackage
            + ".MainActivity");
    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

3). Then in manifest define this service as like below.

```
<service android:name=".AppService" >
    </service>
```

Comment: Hi Meghal, you got me wrong; I don't want to create an application and then its service so it runs in the background. What I want to do is an Xposed module that all it does is hooking to the system method that tells the applications when they have gone to the background and injecting a code in it (could be just a simple XC_MethodReplacement) so X applications don't get that message and they continue running as if they were in the foreground. 
Take a look in the XDA link I posted if you need further explanation.
Thanks

Comment: m Sorry i Forgotted this post that Time . .Will Find Time try to ans it perfectly : In 24 hrs